# How to customise AWS hosted login page button/text?

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-interface, amazon-cognito

So I have found AWS have some great documentation on how to customise hosted UI, and will be modifying it with CSS. However, I would like to change the text in sign in. Currently it displays the user indentity provider within the button and "corporate ID" above I would like to change. Is there a way to customise it to my choosing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I lodged a AWS support ticket and they confirmed you cannot customise the button text or the text above the button (as yet). This is a request they get frequently.

In order to change the name of the text in the button, the user will have to change the name of the identity provider name.

Comment: Did you ever get any feedback from AWS on when/if this would happen?